# unresolved error javax.security.jacc ldap + glassfishserver

Tags: ldap, glassfish-3

I am getting the following error, which, in my opinion, is leading to "request not granted" response from glassfish server even after a successful login using LDAPRealm.

How can I resolve this?

```
(unresolved javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission /* null)
 (unresolved com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicAccessPermission access null)
 (unresolved javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission/*!DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,TRACE)
 (unresolved com.sun.enterprise.security.CORBAObjectPermission * *)
```

my web.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.push.jms.enabled</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            180
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/faces/welcome.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Restricted Access</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
            <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>USERS</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>LDAPRealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>    
    <security-role>
        <role-name>USERS</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```